# How can I use the Graphviz macro in XWiki 2.0 syntax?

Tags: graphviz, xwiki

The XWiki FAQ gives an example for XWiki 1.0 syntax:

```
{graphviz:type=dot}digraph G {Hello->world}{graphviz}
```

My XWiki is properly set up to display this.
But I'm not able to translate this into XWiki 2.0 syntax. I tried this

```
{{graphviz type=dot}} ... {{/graphviz}}
```

and other variations, but the best I got was about "graphviz" not being a valid macro.

As soon as I switch back the document format to the old syntax, it works, so I assume this is not some kind of misconfiguration problem.

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue.

Doesn't look like it is yet supported.  Check out their Jira log:
http://jira.xwiki.org/jira/browse/XWIKI-3984

Answer (score 0):

The [PlantUML extension](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/PlantUML+Macro) is based on Graphviz and it may be used to build **dot** diagrams

For more information see [PlantUML DOT](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/ditaa.html#dot)

Using XWiki 2.0 syntax, just insert this snippet:

```
{{plantuml}}  
@startdot  
digraph G {  
  Hello -> world  
}  
@enddot  
{{/plantuml}}
```